The document-class key-value option problem?
I have the testclass.cls as follows:
\ProvidesClass{testclass}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\RequirePackage{xkeyval}

\define@key{family}{key1}[]{\def\mytext{#1}}
\define@key{family}{key2}[]{\def\MyText{#1}}
\presetkeys{family}{key1=12345, key2=abcde}{}

\DeclareOptionX{text}{\setkeys{family}{#1}}
% \ExecuteOptionsX{text={key1=12345, key2=abcde}}
\ProcessOptionsX

\LoadClass{book}

And the main.tex is:
\documentclass[text={key1=ahahaha}]{testclass}

\begin{document}

\mytext

\MyText

\end{document}

The result is:

However it shows that LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):[text={key1=ahahaha}]. in the log, with the assignment of key1=ahahaha worked? I wonder how to eliminate the warning, and is there any usage error in the example above?

This is a known problem. The best solution is probably to rewrite the calls using the key-val system that is now in the LaTeX kernel instead of using xkeyval. See clsguide.pdf

there are other reasons to avoid xkeyval in new code as there are better options these days.

don't use xkeyval for new code,latex has a standard keyval system for packages now which needs no extra keyval package, and avoids these issues.

I will use the kernal keyval or l3keys instead of xkeyval, thanks all!

@Explorer the kernel setup (based on l3keys) is super powerful and can be fun to work with.

This is a port of your xkeyval usage to ltkeys:
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.cls}
\ProvidesClass{\@currname}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\DeclareKeys[family]
  {
     key1 .store = \mytext
    ,key2 .store = \MyText
  }
\SetKeys[family]{key1=12345, key2=abcde}

\DeclareKeys{text .code = \SetKeys[family]{#1}}
\ProcessKeyOptions

\LoadClass{book}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[text={key1=ahahaha}]{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\mytext

\MyText

\end{document}

If using l3keys properties is fine as well you could also use \DeclareKeys{text .meta:nn = {family}{#1}} instead of the above definition of that key (this will be a tad faster, but the difference is negligible).

\begin{advertisement}
The following uses expkv (I'm the author of that package) to achieve the same.
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.cls}
\ProvidesClass{\@currname}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{expkv-def,expkv-opt}

\ekvdefinekeys{family}
  {
     store   key1 = \mytext
    ,default key1 = {}
    ,initial key1 = 12345
    ,store   key2 = \MyText
    ,default key2 = {}
    ,initial key2 = abcde
  }

\ekvdefinekeys{options}{ smeta text = {family}{#1} }

\ekvoProcessOptions{options}

\LoadClass{book}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[text={key1=ahahaha}]{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\mytext

\MyText

\end{document}

\end{advertisement}
